# IN mybatis query with some hard coded value

Tags: mysql, sql, ibatis

Mybatis is an ORM which have  capacity of dynamically inject values in SQL queries.
Now my query is, if I have some hardcoded value in my query and I want to use it, how do I proceed?

```
select first_name,last_name from employee where dept='CSE';
```

Can IBATIS  support the above query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. iBatis and MyBatis support SQL text that includes literal string values. There's no requirement that all values have to be supplied as placeholders/bind parameters.

Yes, you can have a "hard coded value" in your SQL.

Give it a try.

---

Were you asking how to *replace* a "hard coded value" in your SQL text with a bind parameter?

Reference: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html

Get started with some simple tests.

**FOLLOWUP**

```
<select id="selectEmployeel" parameterType="String" resultMap="employeeMap">
   select first_name,last_name from employee where dept=#{dept}
</select>
```

With no parameters and just a literal string value:

```
<select id="selectEmployee2" resultMap="employeeMap">
   select first_name,last_name from employee where dept='CSE'
</select>
```

Reference: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Comment: I need to write the query in the below format right ,                       ,                              <select id="selectEmployeel" parameterType="String" resultMap="employeeMap">
       select first_name,last_name from employee where dept=#dept#
</select>                                                                                                                         But I want it to write ,                                                                                                           select first_name,last_name from employee where dept='cse'